# In Rails 4 how do I add fields to a form in a DRY manner?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, dry, slim-lang

In my Rails 4 project I want to add 2 fields to all the forms for a controller on the server side.

I'd like to add this to all of my forms for a controller.

```
input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value='=form_authenticity_token'
input name="profilePage" type="hidden" value='#{params[:action]}'
```

Each view has one form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it a partial:

```
#_csrf.html.slim
input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden"value='=form_authenticity_token'
input name="profilePage" type="hidden" value='#{params[:action]}'
```

And then render it in each form:

```
= render 'csrf'
```